# Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql

When I execute this query

```
SELECT
*
FROM
user
INNER JOIN friend
ON user.user_id = friend.friend_id
WHERE friend.user_id = :userId
ORDER BY user.firstName ASC
```

**I get this error:**

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near ':userId    ORDER BY user.firstName ASC' at line 7

Comment: What is :userId ?  That is what it is complaining about.  Aren't variables usually with a @ e.g. @userId ?

Comment: Yes its variable public function getUser(int $userId)
 {
  $user = $this->db->prepare("
   SELECT
    *
   FROM user
   WHERE user_id = ':userId'
  ");

  $user->execute([
   'userId' => $userId
  ]);

  $user = $user->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

  return $user;
 }

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying PHP's PDO query directly in mysql, but mysql couldn't get it, Try to replace `:userId` by actual value you want to compare,